# How to produce the smallest alphabetical letter of either upper or lower case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that produces the smallest alphabetical letter of either lower or upper case. So if the string contains an upper and lower case character which is alphabetically first, I have to return the value of the character which occurs first in the string.

Right now my code only takes an input string all in lower case and finds the smallest (alphabetically first) letter from (a-z). But I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

```
def smallest_ignore_case(string):
    chars = [char for char in string if char.islower()]
    return min(chars) if chars else ""
```

Output I'm supposed to get:

```
assert(smallest_ignore_case("Hello World") == "d")
assert(smallest_ignore_case("HeLLo WorLD") == "D")
assert(smallest_ignore_case("What an AARDVARK!") == "a")
```

Comment: Add sample input and expected output in your question

Comment: You sure your assertions are correct?

Comment: the 2nd assert won't work because your ternary operator is excluding all upper case characters.

Comment: You forgot to mention what's wrong with your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `key`ed `min`; that'll allow you to compare based on case-insensitive values, while returning the original cased value:

```
def smallest_ignore_case(string):
    alphachars = (let for let in string if let.isalpha())  # or filter(str.isalpha, string)
    return min(alphachars, key=str.casefold, default='')
```

The use of the `default` means that if you have no cased characters in the string, `min` helpfully returns the empty string for you, no need for the conditional `if/else` expression. You can use `str.lower` in place of `str.casefold` if you prefer (the latter is just more explicit about converting to common case, and handles some Unicode cases differently).

Using `default` isn't strictly necessary, but it allows you to handle the empty case without forcing you to make a temporary list (using a generator expression or `filter` means you only process a character at a time without storing them all). If you used the listcomp, you could preserve your original `min(...) if alphachars else ''` design.

You existing code doesn't work because it only keeps the lowercase characters in the filtering listcomp (uppercase characters are discarded), and if it didn't do that, it wouldn't perform a case-insensitive comparison of what remained.

Answer (score 1):

First of all instead of taking only lowercase letter, you want to take [**any**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) letter. So change the list-comp to:

```
chars = [char for char in string if char.isalpha()]
```

Then you want to ignore case in your comparison, but still return the matching letter. For that you can give [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) the `key` argument:

```
return min(chars, key=str.lower) if chars else ""
```

All together:

```py
def smallest_ignore_case(string):
    chars = [char for char in string if char.isalpha()]
    return min(chars, key=str.lower) if chars else ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve case of the letter, then you might try smth like this:

```
min_letter = min(string.lower())  # get min letter regardless the case
for l in string:
    if l.lower() == min_letter:
        return l
```

If you don't care about case, then just `min(string.lower())`

Answer (score 0):

The following works if your string has both `upper` and `lower` letters in it.

```
def fn(string):
    lowers_min = min([char for char in string if char.islower()])
    uppers_min = min([char for char in string if char.isupper()])
    if string.index(lowers_min) < string.index(uppers_min):
        return string[string.index(lowers_min)]
    elif string.index(lowers_min) > string.index(uppers_min):
        return string[string.index(uppers_min)]
    else:
        return ''
```